# How to implement Box UI Elements in Vue 2

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to implement Box into a Vue 2 app, following this guide: https://medium.com/box-developer-blog/box-ui-elements-with-vue-3-fad92a28d6b8 (there is none available for Vue 2).

I'm stuck with the steps of Creating a Vue component. The documentation says:

1. Import Box UI Elements from node modules.
2. Next, define the Content Explorer instance and initialise it using via the onMounted lifecycle hook.
3. In order to display the component, just import it to App.vue or to a separate view and pass the folder id as a prop. The value “0” is dedicated to the root folder.

How can I do this in Vue 2? The box-ui-elements folder is installed in my node modules.

My code so far:

```
<template>
  <div class="view--dashboard faq-general-content tickets-panel">
    <div class="ticket-statusses">
        <div id="box-content-explorer" v-if="accessToken"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_DASHBOARD, IS_LOADING } from '../../constants';
import 'box-ui-elements/dist/explorer.js';
import 'box-ui-elements/dist/explorer.css';
import BoxContentExplorer from '../components/BoxContentExplorer.vue'
const api_url = process.env.MIX_API_URL;

export default {
    name: 'Reports',
    components: {
        BoxContentExplorer
    },
    mounted() {
        this.accessToken = process.env.MIX_BOX_DEVELOPER_TOKEN;
        this.contentExplorer = new Box.ContentExplorer();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            accessToken: null,
            folderId: 0,
            contentExplorer: null
        }
    }
}
</script>
```